# How should we break the ice?

Tags: humans, aliens

The year is 2015 A.D. the entire Earth stood still as humanity witness the arrival of an UFO.

A spherical object 10km in diameter is accompanied by 3 earth-sized planets, seemingly in orbit around it.¹

Not only have the alients not initiated communication nor responded to our hails, but it was completely undetected until it appeared suddenly 6 months out.

My question is **how should humanity react** to an uninvited guest from extraterrestrial origin? With so much at stakes and so little time left, should we be proactive or reactive? will Earth becomes its moon regardless of effort? (ETA 6 months, intention unclear, tech unspecified, propulsion speculative, confirmed it's alien)

Note 1: it's important to the story that the 10km probe "own" the 3 Earth-sized objects, as this opens up the idea that it might *take* our Earth, too!  So another issue is how would we tell this is the case and that the tiny probe even exists, rather than just seeing a triangle of 3 masses orbiting a mutual center of gravity?

Comment: If this probe is directly causing the objects to orbit, then its technology is so far beyond us there's nothing we _can_ do. If this probe is causing the orbits by gravity, then it's actually a [magnetar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar) and we're screwed before it even comes near the Solar System.

Comment: @Frostfyre a magnetar don't sneak up on us and is there any way to kill time like put up resistance to dissuade the alien?

Comment: Hm. You're right. A magnetar is actually twice the size of this probe. So, if the planets are orbiting because of gravity, then you're looking at a black hole, which can (kind of) "sneak up" on us. But we're still doomed.

Comment: I saw a documentary on this once. Don't send out helicopters with strange light shows. It doesn't work.

Comment: Voting to close: idea generation, and the question seems to lack basic research regarding sense of scale and space detection technologies.

Comment: @Frostfyre I swear I didn't see this coming, meanie.

Comment: @o.m. you're mistaken it's not lacking in research its the alien whom isn't cooperating! How do I appeal?

Comment: @user6760, that was one vote. One vote by itself isn't enough to close. Regarding research, it sounds as if you found it unusual that this fleet of worlds "elude[d] our radar until now". What radar site should detect targets "near towards the solar system"?

Comment: @o.m. scientists are making objects [invisible to microwave](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial_cloaking) so why can't the alien invent material that is invisible to visible light, IR, radiowave, etc. Unless the object is very massive otherwise the gravitational lensing effect won't be noticeable. I respect your decision nonetheless however pls allow me to defend the OP 

Comment: @o.m. oh I get it you are asking what kind of radar we use to detect threats outside the solar system, we assume alien also communicate by em wave such as radiowave and we are tenaciously trying to pick up this signal even China is building the world largest radio telescope by 2016. Unless alien loves hide and seek that's my OP is about.

Comment: Who needs radar? Look up LSST. I've mentioned it before. Earth-sized objects will be spotted, automatically, at considerable distance. And that's *real*, soon. You need a better understanding of what is possible now and near future, not just a vague understanding that there is a famous telescope named Hubble.

Comment: How would you know there is something 10km in diameter? You would only see the earth-sized bodies.

Comment: @JDlugosz the same idea how astronomers know the est size of Brown dwarf or black hole. Does nobody read my OP or understand my comments 

Comment: "probe with an estimated diameter of 10km draws near" size given.  I don't see anything in your comments elaborating on that. We somehow just know that, and then spot 3 spheres 4000mi in radius using a telescope that must have been told where to aim before it saw that, and impliy that we didn't know about that via other instruments already.  Eluding radar is not the most perplexing, or even a serious question.

Comment: It is "drawing close to the solar system" and our radar hasn't picked it up?  Is radar really used for picking up objects outside the solar system?  Wouldn't the radar screen be over full with all the Kepler objects?  Here's my idea: if Earth sized planets orbit it closer than 150 million km then maybe they weigh less that an Earth size planet (think hologram or some other sort of projection).

Comment: @JDługosz unless absolutely necessary I can and will include a science tag and put in the details however as this is worldbuilding I believe certain level of detail could be omitted as they do not serve to help my OP, my question is not about detection nor the nature of the UFO I'm asking about the reaction from the people upon encountering such phenomenon. Refrain from ganging up on me! you may like to downvote this OP instead, I appreciate your understanding. 

Comment: @user6760 ok I edited the question based on that. Take it as a suggestion/draft.  Removing ref to Radar and just noting that it was unnoticed (by whatever advanced surveys we actually have) until *bam* there it is, opens another idea too: it materialized there dropping out of FTL?

Comment: Another comment rather than an A because it doesn't answwr the question but criticises the situation:  if 3 Earths appeared around the orbit of Jupiter, wouldn't it pretty much wreck the solar system?  As it drew nearer it would peturb the orbits of the inner planets, significantly.

Comment: @JDługosz thanks for the edit I would like the alien propulsion to remain speculative if possible. Unless there is a planetary alignment!

Comment: Planetary alignment? I don't follow.  Are the objects acting like they have a source of thrust, rather than just falling around the sun? If not, there is no propulsion other than how did they get there without being seen to arrive.

Answer (score 4):

What can the central object be?

1. Black hole surround by an constructed shell.
2. Artificially constructed neutron star -- 20 km diameter is smallest naturally occurring neutron star.
3. Artificial construct generating an intense gravitational field or equivalent to bind the 3 planets.
4. Something else even more incomprehensible to us.

Only case 1 sounds like something we could even plan on doing, assuming we just happened to find a primordial black hole. Once again, the central diameter is too small for a black hole from a star. The naked singularity is smaller, but it is below the event horizon and nothing could be constructed and visible existing inside the horizon. So you need a primordial black hole smaller than 10km. To keep the 3 planets in orbit, it still need to fairly massive. Just getting close to the earth will cause lots of problems for us.

The technology to build the shell able to withstand the tidal forces is yet again magic level. Also any inhabitants would be ripped up by tidal forces unless they are artificial or protected by gravity control or suchlike.

I don't carry on a conversation with ants. I ignore them or destroy them as I please. The ants have no say in the matter. Now, an entomologist might be interested in studying the ants, someone else might want an ant farm. But in no case do the ants have any influence in the outcome. Should the ants bite or get into my food, I am more likely to destroy them than otherwise.

Just getting here from another star star implies technology well beyond our current level. Doing so in style bringing along 3 planets and something beyond our understanding at the core ups the game by a huge amount. The aliens are far, far beyond our technology.

If the aliens are for some reason friendly, they will study us, contact us, etc. as they see fit. If they are hostile, we are completely toast. If they are indifferent, it would be best not to annoy them.

The winning strategy is to lay low and respond politely if they initiate contact. Maybe we should try to be on our best behavior, knock off the local wars, etc. to look like a cute puppy instead of a mad dog that should just be put out of its misery.

Answer (score 1):

The comments thread is getting a bit unwieldly for answers with links so I'm putting this into the answer format, even if it is really a comment. I questioned the question as (a) too broad when it comes to human reaction and (b) not consistent with 2015 detection technology.

Say an object with 10 km diameter comes from deep space into the solar system, orbited by three planet-sized objects (call them 10,000 km diameter).

- Detecting the triple planet should be about as difficult as detecting Pluto and Charon from Earth. Pluto was initially discovered by looking at [disturbances of other planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto#Discovery). Current surveys use [telescopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalina_Sky_Survey). *No radar involved, so the lack of a radar signature **of the probe** is not detected.*
- Once the unusual triple planet is detected ([Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto) has just two big ones) people on Earth might direct their attention there. Here is a picture of Pluto [from Earth](http://www.space.com/17784-best-pluto-photo-from-earth-picture.html). This is what [Hubble](http://hubblesite.org/newscenter/archive/releases/solar-system/pluto/2010/06/) tells us about Pluto.
- The three bodies would be expected to orbit around their common center of gravity. Some scientists might ask why they didn't [crash into each other long ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem), but the average guy on the street wouldn't understand the question.
- Pluto has plenty of [moons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Pluto), so a short glimpse of the alien probe should be dismissed as something like that.

So we wouldn't **expect** detailed data from those strange worlds until we get a probe into the area. The probe would carry a limited set of sensors and rush by with in a single high-speed pass, all predetermined when the mission was designed.

At best we'd get [ambiguous readings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cydonia_%28region_of_Mars%29) from the scientific sensors, and we'd debate for decades if they warrant the expense of a new mission to look closer. Perhaps there will be a [History Channel](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/TheHistoryChannel) episode. Sceptics would call for another planetary science mission, instead of wasting money on a weird alien hunt.

**Summary:** Earth doesn't stand still, because Earth doesn't really notice anything weird with 2015 tech.

Comment: Maybe the new horizons probe just happened to be in the area and noticed the alien probe, so they pointed the Hubble to try and investigate the unexpected change in trajectory. Yeah, you're right the question was pretty far fetched this way too.